# In Unity 2021.3, is there a way to search my project files for all prefabs that have a specific component attached to them?

Tags: unity

If many of my prefabs have an `ExampleComponent.cs` attached to them, how can I use Unity's built-in search to find them?

If such a search isn't possible, what are some tips for organizing one's assets so that things are more searchable as my project grows in complexity?

Comment: If you want to use the build in search, making a test scene, add all prefabs you have to it and now you can right click on your script and select `Find references in scene` might be a fast workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity Editor allows you to find usages of an asset in scene only. You can implement resource search through some third-party scripts like [this](https://www.powerhoof.com/find-object-references-in-unity/).

Put the code in the editor directory, right-click a script (resource) and a new search button will appear.

[image]

It basicly uses [EditorUtility.CollectDependencies](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.CollectDependencies.html):

> Calculates and returns a list of all assets the assets listed in roots depend on.

Recursively traverse all resources with the specified suffix in the Assets directory, access the resources they depend on. so that you can find out which resources the specified resource is referenced by.